# Calculator - clicking on buttons do not work

Tags: javascript, calculator

I have a question: 
I do not why but my simple calculator is not working. If I click on any  -> "my Button" of my calculator nothing is working and Javascript is not executing. The numbers or operators are not passed to display in  -> "#screen" Do you see where is the problem?

HTML FILE:

```
<BODY>

<table>

<tr>
<td id="buttonCE">C</td>
<td colspan=3 id="screen" >0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td  class="buttonNumber" >7</td>
  <td  class="buttonNumber" >8</td>
  <td  class="buttonNumber" >9</td>
  <td  class="buttonNumber" >/</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td  class="buttonNumber" >4</td>
  <td  class="buttonNumber" >5</td>
  <td  class="buttonNumber" >6</td>
  <td  class="buttonOperator" >-</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td  class="buttonNumber" >1</td>
  <td  class="buttonNumber" >2</td>
  <td  class="buttonNumber" >3</td>
  <td  class="buttonOperator" >+</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td  class="buttonNumber">0</td>
  <td  class="buttonOperator" >.</td>
  <td  id="buttonResult" >=</td>
  <td  class="buttonOperator">*</td>
</tr>
</table>

<script src="new.js"></script> 
<script src="app.js"></script>      

</BODY>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE - NEW.JS:

```
'use strict'


var screen = document.querySelector('#screen').textContent




 const eraseFunction = () => {  
    const ceKey = document.querySelector('#buttonCE')
    debugger
    ceKey.onclick = function(e) {
    screen = "" }
}


const resultFunction = () => {
    const resultKey = document.querySelector('#buttonResult') 
    resultKey.onclick = () => {
        let lastCharOfScreen = screen[screen.length-1]
        if (lastCharOfScreen!='+' || lastCharOfScreen!='-' || lastCharOfScreen!='/' || lastCharOfScreen!='*' || lastCharOfScreen!='.' ) {
            screen = eval(screen) }
        else {
            screen = eval(screen.substring(0, screen.length))
        }
    }

}


const numberFunction = () => {
    let numberKeys = document.querySelectorAll('.buttonNumber')
    for (let i=0; i<numberKeys.length; i++) {
        numberKeys[i].onclick = () => {
            let buttonNumberValue = this.innerHTML
            if (screen.length!=1 && screen!=0) {
                screen += buttonNumberValue
            }

        }
    }
}


const operatorFunction = () => {
    let operatorKeys = document.querySelectorAll('.buttonOperator')
    for (let i=0; i<operatorKeys.length; i++) {
        operatorKeys[i].onclick = (e) => {
            let buttonOperatorValue = this.innerHTML
            let lastCharOfScreen = screen[screen.length-1]

            // 1st conditional
            if (screen.length = 0 && buttonOperatorValue=="-") {
                screen+=buttonOperatorValue
            }


            if (screen.length>0) {
            // 2nd conditional
                if (lastCharOfScreen!=buttonOperatorValue) {
                screen += buttonNumberValue
                }

        }
    }
    }

}
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE -> APP.JS:

```
'use strict'

eraseFunction()
resultFunction()
numberFunction()
operatorFunction()
```

Comment: What errors are in the console?

Comment: When I use Visual Studio Code and run Debug on new.js then I receive an error: ReferenceError: document is not defined

Comment: e:\calculator\new.js:4
var screen = document.querySelector('#screen').textContent
             ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (e:\Nowy folder\StronaWWW\Kalkulator\new.js:4:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)

Comment: when I use Visual Studio Code and run Debug on app.js then I received an error: ReferenceError: eraseFunction is not defined  -> which I think is strange due to made statement in new.js and proper order of loading script files in HTML File

Comment: Have you actually tried to open the web page in a web browser?

Comment: Yes, many times ;). Nothing happens. I click buttons -> but no numbers or other operators are passed/shown in display/screen

Comment: "_Nothing happens_" You don't get any javascript errors in the browser console?

Comment: no errors in Chrome Browser Console

Comment: When I load this up and click on numbers I get lots of console errors. I think you should check again.

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors.

Here you are trying to set screen.length to 0, which is invalid. Length is read only.

`if (screen.length = 0 && buttonOperatorValue=="-") {`

Should be:

`if (screen.length == 0 && buttonOperatorValue=="-") {`

Here `buttonNumberValue` is not defined. Not sure what you meant it to be:

```
if (screen.length>0) {
    // 2nd conditional
    if (lastCharOfScreen!=buttonOperatorValue) {
         screen += buttonNumberValue
    }
}
```

I'd also recommend using semicolons to end your statements in JavaScript and formatting your code properly.

I **strongly** recommend taking a look at the console for errors. You won't get very far without looking at errors yourself and debugging.

Comment: Thanks. I changed these 2 error swhich you found. Now is better. Unfortunatelly I still can not run/click buttons to see running calculations in prepared table/calculator.